# Resources Exceeded During Query Execution: Custom Dimensions & MAX(IF(...))

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm performing what I thought was a simple events query in BigQuery with two custom dimensions. When trying to execute this query for year-to-date, I get the following error:

> query: Resources exceeded during query execution. (error code:
>   resourcesExceeded)

Research of this error and investigation of the 'resourcesExceeded' error code indicates that this happens most frequently when using windowed functions, joins, count(distinct()) or group by each, none of which I am using here. The only thing I am doing is `order by Date asc`, which doesn't appear to eliminate the error when that line is removed. Since this is a shard resources issue, I think this has to be related to the two custom dimensions I'm trying to pull, since the MAX/IF function seem to be the most resource intensive portions of this query. Here's a snippet of the query I'm running:

```
SELECT 
      DATE,
      userId,
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      trafficSource.source,
      trafficSource.medium,
      trafficSource.campaign,
      trafficSource.adContent,
      MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.INDEX = 1,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS XXXXXX,
      MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.INDEX = 2,hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS YYYYYY,
      totals.visits,
      totals.bounces,
      totals.pageviews
FROM (
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE([########.ga_sessions_], 
            TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01'), # start date
            TIMESTAMP('2016-07-31')) # end date
      )
ORDER BY DATE ASC;
```

I've tried this query both through the BigQuery console UI as well as from the command line. I've also set the option, 'allowLargeResults' to True.

Comment: Do you have a job id?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa yes, each query is assigned a universally unique (job) ID

Comment: would you share it? (for debugging purposes)

Comment: Sorry Felipe, I didn't recognize who you were! One of the problematic job IDs is default-1223:bquijob_3bd250b5_156513552b9, though there were other similar queries that were affected.